# Flask: Why can't I store a cookie without a response?

Tags: python, cookies, flask, response

In the Flask documentation, it gives the following example code:

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/')
def index():
    resp = make_response(render_template(...))
    resp.set_cookie('username', 'the username')
    return resp
```

Why is it necessary to make a response object? Can't cookies be set whenever with javascript?

Comment: In most languages cookie operations are done on response object. The two I know are Java, javascript (nodejs) express framework.

Comment: Can I just make an arbitrary redirect but not actually follow through with that redirect, just to get the response, then set the cookie on that response?

Comment: Yes of course, you can just set a cookie and redirect the user. But I don't know how to do it in flask.

Comment: @Oliver Do you want to set the cookie and redirect the user elsewhere?

Comment: I figured it out; I just didn't understand request and response objects. To be clear, my question was can I set the cookie **without** the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key insight was that routes expect response objects, so when you to render_template(..) or redirect(url_for(..)) that returns a response object containing your rendered view. It doesn't really matter that you set the cookie right away, you generally have to return a response on any route anyway, so might as well do it there if it is convenient.

Comment: How did you achieve this behavior?